# Installing kvm /dev/kvm missing

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to install kvm extensions in my computer.

I'm following this guide

[KVM installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation)

KVM is not available in my machine and I have a 32 bits one.

```
rocio@rocio-laptop:~$ sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok
  INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
  KVM acceleration can NOT be used
rocio@rocio-laptop:~$ uname -m
   i686
```

Everything seems to be ok until the verifying

```
rocio@rocio-laptop:~$ ls -l /dev/kvm
  ls: no se puede acceder a /dev/kvm: No existe el archivo o el directo
```

that means in spanish the file or folder doesnt exist.

Where is the problem?

I add some information after the bodhi.zazen's answer.

I have 2 processor:

```
rocio@rocio-laptop:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
     processor  : 0
     vendor_id  : GenuineIntel
     cpu family : 6
     model      : 23
     model name : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T6400  @ 2.00GHz
```

But none Intel or AMD:

```
rocio@rocio-laptop:~$ grep vmx /proc/cpuinfo
rocio@rocio-laptop:~$ grep svm /proc/cpuinfo
rocio@rocio-laptop:
```

Also, in Intel website, it seems to be a 64 bits processor

http://ark.intel.com/products/40479/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T6400-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB

I'm lost!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message:

```
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

And your processor is an i686

See:

http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Processor_support

and

http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/FAQ#Are_64bits_processors_supported_under_KVM.3F

So to use KVM you need to upgrade your processor

You can use Virtualbox and qemu, but they will be slower then KVM

Comment: I updated my cuestion with your suggest

Comment: @cucuru Your CPU still does not support KVM. You need a new, "modern" cpu if you wish to run KVM. Perhaps if you installed a 64 bit version of Ubuntu, but cpuinfo should show the flags

Comment: so, I need a new computer???

Comment: A CPU that support KVM, yes. See the links. You need a CPUu with either the vmx or svm flags

Comment: @cucuru - On the link to your CPU "Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x) ‡ No" you need a CPU that has ("yes') to this feature